# GET RestSharp request returns null value if the Content-Type is "text/plain", whereas if Content-Type is "application/json" data is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I've started to learn some MVC, and am looking at creating a dashboard using a Restful API. So far, everything is going fairly well, however, I've come across what I imagine is a very simple fix which I can't seem to figure out.

If I make a GET request to part of the API which has a application/json as the response body, then everything works fine. If, however, the response body returns a text/plain value, then all I receive is a null value.

When I access the API URL in a web browser or Postman it simply returns a number, so this shouldn't be a complex issue, I'm just missing something obvious because of my lack of knowledge.

How can I return the data of an API using text/plain?

This is the code that I am using within my Controller:

```
   var client = new RestClient("http://URL:1234/api/");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("XXXXX", "XXXXX");
            var ErrorQueue = new RestRequest("errorqueue/count", Method.GET);
            ErrorQueue.AddHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
            ViewBag.errorQueueTotal = client.Execute<DashboardModel>(ErrorQueue).Data;
```

This is the code within my Model:

```
public class DashboardModel
{

    public DataModel data { get; set; }

}

public class DataModel
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string uptime { get; set; }
    public int errors { get; set; }
}
```

And just for reference, here is my view which is calling the ViewBag:

```
 <div class="container">
    <h3>Error Queue</h3>
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-default-Messages">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <label>Error Queue: </label>
            <span id="errorSpanID">@ViewBag.errorQueueTotal.data.errors</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe that the issue lies with how I'm trying to return the data once the API has been requested, but some clarification on where I'm going wrong would be really helpful.

Comment: @ViewBag.errorQueueTotal.errors

Comment: It also looks like you have a type when you set the ViewBag.  You put .Data, but DashboardModel defines a property data.

Comment: Hi Fran, I've now amended the code. It was originally correct, but I've been chopping and changing which is why it was wrong in the post. I still, unfortunately, receive a null value. I need the .Data type, otherwise I receive an error that RestSharp.RestResponse does not contain a definition for 'data'.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a null check on what you call is returning before you try to get the .Data property.  I'm confused about this .data .Data thing.  You are setting a property on the viewbag to the .Data value.  Where is this extra .data coming in when you call it in your view.

Comment: I definitely need a null check. The .Data in the controller is the deserialized entity data when the request is executed. The .data in the View is coming from the class that is located within my Model. When the content is JSON, the data, when deserialized, is stored in the corresponding DataModel class variable. From within the ViewBag, I then call the relevant variable from the DataModel class. This is how I am interpreting it, I could be incorrect though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick thanks to Fran for taking the time to comment and assist.

The code below is what I have used to resolve the issue. I'm not totally sure why RestSharp was returning a null value, when it worked for all the other GET requests I've made. None the less, this works perfectly for me! :)

```
var clienttest = new WebClient();
            clienttest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXXX", "XXXXX");
            var response = clienttest.DownloadString("http://XXXXX:1234/api/Test/1234/state");
            ViewBag.details = response.ToString();
```